# Is it ok that my asus k501lb will be plugged in always?

Tags: laptop, battery

I have my asus k501lb laptop and it seems that the laptop's battery is non-removable, what is the disadvantage of this laptop battery? Is it good or not?... it seems that the new laptop now are none removable just like any smartphones... what is the alternative of this? I always use my laptop though for work.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the disadvantage of this laptop battery

That you cannot *easily* replace it.

> Is it good or not

That's for you to decide. If you were hoping to use the laptop for, say, more than a couple years, then maybe it would have been better if you bought a laptop with an easy-to-replace battery.

> seems that the new laptop now are none removable just like any smartphones

Yup, some of them.

> what is the alternative of this?

You can buy a laptop that has an easy-to-replace battery. You might have to spend a bit more money though.

> I always use my laptop though for work.

Good for you :-)

> Is it ok that my asus k501lb will be plugged in always?

No problem at all. The only (small) disadvantage is that the battery will stay at 100% charge which will decrease its life somewhat. Shouldn't make a difference to you if you're going have it plugged in all the time though.

Answer (score 0):

Batteries need to be exercised (the charge/drain cycle). If not, they will eventually lose the ability to hold a charge. Granted this will eventually happen anyway, but it will happen much faster for a battery that is always plugged in. Fortunately my laptop has an easily removable battery separate from the A/C cord, so I remove the battery from the laptop when I know it'll be plugged in for an extended period.